# How to draw (semi-)logarithmic 3d plots? (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, mesh, surf

I know semilogx and semilogy for 2D plots. There is any equivalent for SURF and MESH?

Comment: I don't think you've any choice but to do the log calculation yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at the *XScale*, *YScale* and *Zscale* axis properties.  You can set them to either *linear* or *log*.  However, to set these properties to *log* the data needs to be positive.  See http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/239232 for more details.

Comment: Thanks, now I have the same problem as the guy that asked the question you linked: the color now is pretty much the same, how to correct it? You can answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433769/how-to-get-beauty-color-scale-on-semi-logarithmic-3d-plots-on-matlab

Comment: I missed that problem.  I have placed some hints on my other question but can't test right now. If I find time I will play around with Matlab to see if I can get something to work.

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the mentioned link, to set all three axes to logarithmic scaling, use

```
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log', 'YScale', 'log', 'ZScale', 'log')
```