# How to get a beautiful color scale on (semi-)logarithmic 3d plots on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, mesh, surf

After having [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433364/how-to-draw-semi-logarithmic-3d-plots-matlab) answered through a link to [an external site](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/239232), I realized that I solved a problem, just to get another one: On a logarithm scale the C=Z parameter of MESH and SURF functions don't work very well. All you get is a blue graph, without the usual color gradient, that you get by passing 3 parameters.

How to revert that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the [*caxis*](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/caxis.html) command?  I could also suggest that you look at the [*CData*](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surface_props.html#CData) and [*CDataMapping*](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/surface_props.html#CDataMapping) properties of the surface handle object.  I hope these links point in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

I'll piggyback on @[Azim's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433769/how-to-get-a-beautiful-color-scale-on-semi-logarithmic-3d-plots-on-matlab#433801) answer.  Using caxis, you should be able to define logarithmic breakpoints for your color scheme, which will prevent your entire graph from going to blue.  I don't remember if this can be done automatically with graph properties.